# Symfony2 Unrecognized options simple_preauth

Tags: php, security, symfony, authentication, service

I wrote custom user authenticator following the documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/api_key_authentication.html
and while i add in app/security.yml

```
    pattern: ^/
    stateless: true
    simple_preauth:
        authenticator: sso_authenticator
```

it says:
`InvalidConfigurationException: Unrecognized options "simple_preauth" under "security.firewalls.secured_area"`
what can couse that problem how to solve it ?

Comment: Which version of Symfony2 do you use? It's available only in 2.4

Comment: yes, this was a reason, i updated version from 2.3 to 2.4 now its ok! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is caused because of version. simple_preauth option is created in symfony 2.4. more reference [SimplePreAuthenticationFactory.php](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/SecurityBundle/DependencyInjection/Security/Factory/SimplePreAuthenticationFactory.php)